# Starting a *.bat from a *.vbs giving the dos box a special size and position on the screen

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, cmd, dosbox

I would like to ask if there is a way to start a *.bat from a *.vbs - with a special dos box size - and move the dos box to a special position on my screen.

At the moment I use this VBS code:

```
Dim WshShell
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run Left(WScript.ScriptFullName, InStrRev(WScript.ScriptFullName, "\")) & "test.bat"
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Run Method (Windows Script Host)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(v=vs.84).aspx) reference.